# Is there a way to create a python module using SWIG C++ which can be imported in both Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, swig

I'm writing a SWIG c++ file to generate a python module. I want to let the users import it in both Python2 and Python3 scripts. Since SWIG has different flags for binding Python2 and Python 3, I was wondering is there a way I can write a create a general module for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewind a little and keep SWIG itself out of the question to start with.

Historically it's been necessary to compile a Python module for every (sometimes even minor) version change of the Python interpreter. This led to [PEP-384](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0384/), which defined a stable ABI for a subset of the Python C-API from Python 3.2 onwards. So obviously that doesn't actually work for your request, because you're interested in 2 vs 3. Furthermore SWIG itself doesn't actually generate [PEP-384 compatible](https://sourceforge.net/p/swig/feature-requests/78/), code.

To experiment further and see a bit more about what's going on I've made the following SWIG file:

```c
%module test
%inline %{
  char *frobinate(const char *in) {
    static char buf[1024];
    snprintf(buf, 1024, "World of hello: %s", in);
    return buf;
  }
%}
```

If we try to compile this with `-DPy_LIMITED_API` it failed:

```
swig3.0 -Wall -python test.i && gcc -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/include/python3.2 -shared -o _test.so test_wrap.c -DPy_LIMITED_API 2>&1|head
test_wrap.c: In function ‘SWIG_PyInstanceMethod_New’:
test_wrap.c:1114:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyInstanceMethod_New’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   return PyInstanceMethod_New(func);
   ^
test_wrap.c:1114:3: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
test_wrap.c: In function ‘SWIG_Python_UnpackTuple’:
test_wrap.c:1315:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyTuple_GET_SIZE’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     Py_ssize_t l = PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args);
     ^
test_wrap.c:1327:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyTuple_GET_ITEM’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

I.e. nobody has picked up that ticket, at least not on the version of SWIG 3.0.2 that I am testing with.

So where does that leave us? Well the [SWIG 3.0 documentation on Python 3 support](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_python3support) says something interesting:

> SWIG is able to support Python 3.0. **The wrapper code generated by SWIG can be compiled with both Python 2.x or 3.0**. Further more, by passing the -py3 command line option to SWIG, wrapper code with some Python 3 specific features can be generated (see below subsections for details of these features). The -py3 option also disables some incompatible features for Python 3, such as -classic.

My reading of that statement is that if you want to generate source code that can be compiled with both 2.x and 3.x Python headers all you need to do is omit the `-py3` argument when running SWIG. And that seems to work with my testing, the same code generated by SWIG compiles just fine with all of:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -shared -o _test.so test_wrap.c 
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/include/python3.2 -shared -o _test.so test_wrap.c 
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/include/python3.4 -shared -o _test.so test_wrap.c
```

(Note that 3.4 does generate some warnings, but no errors and it does work)

The problem is that there's no interchangeability between the compiled _test.so of any given version. Trying to import a version from one in another will fail with errors from the dynamic linker about missing or undefined symbols. So we're still stuck at the initial problem, although we can compile our module for any Python interpreter we can't compile it for all versions.

*In my view the right way to deal with this is use [distuitls](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn6) and simply install your module into the search path for each version of Python you want to support on any given machine.*

That said there is a workaround we could use. Essentially we want to build multiple versions of our module for each interpreter and use some generic code to switch between the various implementations. Assuming that you're not building with code generated from SWIG's `-builtin` option there are two places we could try and do this:

1. In the shared object itself
2. In some Python code

The later is substantially simpler to achieve, so let's look at that. I did something by using the following bash script to build a shared object for each version of Python I intended to support:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for v in 2.7 3.2 3.4
do
    d=$(echo $v|tr . _)
    mkdir -p $d
    touch $d/__init__.py
    gcc -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/include/python$v -shared -o $d/_test.so test_wrap.c
done
```

This builds 3 versions of _test.so, in directories named after the Python version they're intended to support. If we tried to import our SWIG generated module now it would complain because there's no indication of where to find the `_test` module we've compiled. So we need to fix that. There are three ways to do it:

1. Modify the SWIG generated [import code](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_package_search). I didn't manage to make this work with SWIG 3.0.2 - perhaps it's too old?
2. Modify the Python search path, before the second import. We can do that using `%pythonbegin`:

   ```
   %pythonbegin %{
   import os.path
   import sys
   sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '%d_%d' % (sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor)))
   %}
   ```
3. Write a _test.py stub that finds the right one and then switches them around:

   ```
   from sys import version_info,modules
   from importlib import import_module
   real_mod = import_module('%d_%d.%s' % (version_info.major, version_info.minor, __name__))
   modules[__name__] = modules[real_mod.__name__]
   ```

Either of the last two options worked and resulted in `import test` succeeding in all three versions of Python. But it's cheating a bit really and far better just to install from source 3 times over.

Comment: So I'll have to include "#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3" in the interface file and build the wrapper files separately for different python version?


I can't change the output file since it is being bundled with a software after being compiled.

Comment: All the ifdefs you need are generated automatically and the code will work for both 2 and 3 provided you don't use -py3. You will need to build it once per python version though.